# Running Vulnerable Web Apps in Docker

Tags: docker, security, web-applications

I would like to assess multiple Security Testing Tools (like OWASP ZAP) by running them against multiple **vulnerable web applications** (like Damn Vulnerable Web Application - DVWA).

I know running vulnerable web applications while being in a network connected to the web might be dangerous and not the best idea. But is it also unsafe to **run these apps inside docker containers**?
Would that be a good option without having to consider getting hacked or should i **disconnect** from the web while running these apps inside docker?

Unfortunately, i dont know much about how abstracted a docker image is from the rest of my pc and what possibilities a pwned server inside a docker container would have. Thank you

Comment: I see a close reason for [su] but I think this could be better suited at [security.se]. Whichever site, [so] is for programming questions only, and this one isn't.

Comment: While this is on topic for [security.se], there are plenty of posts dealing with this there already. See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/152978/235964, https://security.stackexchange.com/q/169642/235964. TL;DR: VMs provide better isolation than docker containers. Docker is easier to misconfigure and potentially easier to break out of. Use a VM if possible.

Comment: Ok, then i'll ask again on Information Security. Thank you